# Неправильная работа цикла while, но не могу понять в чем заключается проблема

Tags: c, if, while

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

int main ()
{
    FILE *number, *definition;
    int x, y;
    printf ("Enter the definition number :");
    scanf ("%d", &x);

    number = fopen ("number.txt", "wt");
    fprintf (number, "%d", x);
    fclose (number);

    number = fopen ("number.txt", "r");
    definition = fopen ("definition.txt", "w");
    fscanf (number, "%d", &y);
    printf ("%d\n", y);
    fclose (number);
    fprintf (definition, "%d\n", y);
    fclose (definition);

    scanf ("%d", &y);
    while (1)
    {
        if (y == 1)
            printf("CPU is an electronic unit or an integrated circuit that executes machine instructions, the main part of the hardware of a computer or a programmable logic controller.");
        if (y == 2)
            printf("RAM is in most cases an energy-dependent part of a computer memory system, in which the executed machine code is stored during computer operation.");
        if (y == 3)
            printf("A motherboard is a printed circuit board that is the basis for building a modular electronic device, for example, a computer.");
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Пробовал разные варианты, через goto, ставил/убирал фигурные скобки и т.д.
Ошибка заключается в том, что при вводе в консоль например, значение 1, код "съедает" это значение, а если потом ввести еще раз 1, то они складываются и выводится if( y == 2 ), при чем бесконечное кол-во раз.(Сразу прошу прощения,за то как оформлен мой код тут, не совсем понимаю как надо его оформлять)

Comment: Так у вас внутри `while` переменная `y` не меняется, поэтому будет либо вечный цикл с одинаковым выводом, либо, если ни один `if` не сработает, будет просто вечно висеть код. А в остальном - вы можете сами во всём разобраться, если уберёте для начала весь лишний код, оставите самый минимум, и будете постепенно добавлять код и запускать его. Сейчас у вас слишком много всего сразу этот код делает, не удивительно, что вы запутываетесь.

Comment: Про переменную y. То есть, мне нужно больше переменных чем y?

Answer (score 0):

Ну программа у вас и запрограммирована так, как вы описали.
Всего вы вводите с клавиатуры 2 значения - x и y. Между ними - самодостаточная работа с файлами, которая не требует реакции от пользователя. И да, после того, как вы ввели `x`, вы ничего с ним не делаете.

```
int main ()
{
    ....
    scanf ("%d", &x);
    ....
    scanf ("%d", &y);
    ....
```

А потом у вас стоит "вечный" цикл `while(1)`. Вы ведь не сделали никакого условия для выхода из цикла. Если второе значение - `y` равно 1,2 или 3 - то цикл будет вечно печатать одну из строчек. А если `y` равен другому числу - то цикл будет работать вечно и ничего не печатать.

```
    scanf ("%d", &y);
    while (1)
    {
        if (y == 1)
            printf("CPU is an ....");
        if (y == 2)
            printf("RAM is ....");
        if (y == 3)
            printf("A motherboard is a ....");
    }
```

Так что цикл у вас работает правильно!
А как по-вашему программа должна работать?

Comment: По сути, передо мной стоит задача сделать программу, чтобы пользователь вводил значение 2, и у него выводилось в консоль надпись "RAM is .....", и что бы после этого действия, программа не выключалась, и можно было ввести например, значение 3, и в консоль уже выведется "A motherboard is a....". Без цикла все работает замечательно, с циклом - не очень)

Comment: А зачем тогда 2/3 кода работы с файлами? Может попробуете сами написать то, что сказали? А не то, что где-то скопипастили?